# How to add rewrite rule for redirecting url in Apache Web Server

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I am trying to configure autodiscover feature of outlook and thunderbird for my mail server.

I have added a virtualhost entry with following `RewriteRule` to redirect `config-v1.1.xml` to `thunderbird.php` and `autodiscover.xml` to `outlook.php`.

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.153:80
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.153:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@test.int
    DocumentRoot /var/www/webroot
    ServerName autconfig.test.int
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/mail/config-v1\.1\.xml$ thunderbird.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^/autodiscover/autodiscover\.xml outlook.php [NC,L]
</VirtualHost>`
```

Can anyone tell me what the error is as I am getting error 404 not found?
I have not made any `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Are `thunderbird.php` and `outlook.php` files present in `/var/www/webroot` ?

Comment: What does your error log say?

Comment: @edvinas.me Yes thunderbird.php and outlook.php are present in /var/www/webroot

Comment: Oh I just noticed you don't have `<Directory>` clause.

Comment: Please try my answer

Answer (score 1):

You must define redirects in `<Directory>` clause like this:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.153:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@test.int
    DocumentRoot /var/www/webroot
    ServerName autconfig.test.int

    <Directory "/var/www/webroot">
         Allow from All
         AllowOverride all
         RewriteEngine On
         RewriteRule ^/mail/config-v1\.1\.xml$ thunderbird.php [NC,L]
         RewriteRule ^/autodiscover/autodiscover\.xml outlook.php [NC,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Still receiving the same error 404 not found error

Comment: Are you trying to access `http://autconfig.test.int/mail/config-v1.1.xml` and `http://autconfig.test.int/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml` ? It is possible that some other VHost is replying to your requests. Do you have more configurations?

Comment: yes this one http://autoconfig.test.int/mail/config-v1.1.xml i have added entry in /etc/hosts file

Comment: can you place `index.html` file in `/var/www/webroot` and check `http://autconfig.test.int` to make sure that your requests are handled by this VHost but not by some other one which overwrites it.

Comment: yes i am getting the default page of index.html 
/mail/config-v1.1.xml doesn't exist on server

Comment: i have added alias

Comment: it worked when i added DirectoryIndex index.html

Comment: "You must define redirects in `<Directory>`" - this is incorrect. Moving these (rewrites) to a `<Directory>` container and enabling `.htaccess` ("`AllowOverride all`") will mean that they will potentially be overridden by `.htaccess` (by default). However, since these rules have a slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ they won't match anyway in a _directory_ context.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/mail/config-v1\.1\.xml$ thunderbird.php [NC,L]
> RewriteRule ^/autodiscover/autodiscover\.xml outlook.php [NC,L]
> ```

You can't specify a *relative* substitution string a server (or vhost) context when issuing an *internal rewrite*. It is not seen as relative to the DocumentRoot (or ServerRoot). The examples given in the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) simple state this is "invalid, not supported". On my test server, this actually results in a 400 Bad Request (not a 404 Not Found) - although that no doubt will depend on the server config.

In a server context, you need to specify either an absolute *filesystem* path or a document-root relative (starting with a slash) URL-path. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^/mail/config-v1\.1\.xml$ /thunderbird.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/autodiscover/autodiscover\.xml /outlook.php [NC,L]
```